# insert Parameter and column from table to one table sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS Office 2019, I have 2 tables:

- tblPerson (idPerson, idCategory)

```
tblPerson
-----------------------
idPerson | idCategory |
----------------------+
01       |   03       |
02       |   02       |
03       |   03       |
04       |   01       |
05       |   01       |
06       |   01       |
---------+------------+
```

- I want to create 2nd table, containing:
- tblPersonByDate(idPerson , date_A)
- insert into tblPersonByDate(tblPerson.idPerson , @date_A)

```
tblPersonByDate
-----------------------
idPerson | date_A     |
----------------------+
01       | 2019-01-02 |
02       | 2019-01-02 |
03       | 2019-01-02 |
04       | 2019-01-02 |
05       | 2019-01-02 |
06       | 2019-01-02 |
---------+------------+
```

my query don't work

```
INSERT INTO tblPersonByDate (idPerson,date_A)
VALUES( (SELECT idPerson 
         FROM tblPerson
         )
         , @date__A)
```

Comment: Where does this date come from?

Comment: insert into t2 select id, ... from t1...

Comment: insert into tblPersonByDate(tblPerson.idPerson,@date_A)

Comment: what have you tried? and as mentioned by @Mureinik where does this date come from?

Comment: @date_A Parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand from question , the date come from sql param
you can use insert into table from select statement

```
insert into tblPersonByDate(idPerson, date_A)
select idPerson  ,@date_A From tblPerson
```

Comment: What is something you did not understand . 1st column (idPerson) from tblPerson and 2nd column(date_A) it is parameter enter manual